# Cakephp, order find by related model field

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a News model that has many Comments. What I need is to find ten News that has new Comments.

At first this task is seems to be eazy, I just need to find last ten Comments ($this->Comment->find('all');) and just display related News, but in case I have 2 comments for the same news I will recieve a duplicated news entry.

So, can I order News by Comments date or something?

*And here is solution. Thanks Dave

```
$this->Comment->find('all', array(
    'order' => array(
        'Comment.created' => 'DESC'
    ),
    'group' => 'News.id',
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL's "GROUP BY" ('group' option in CakePHP).  More details:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions